# How to format the exponent of a floating point number in printf %E (scientific)

Tags: ruby, formatting, printf

When I use

`sprintf('%E',@value)`

for some large arbitrary value,

e.g. `3.14158995322368e+22f`

it prints

3.14158995322368e+ **0** 22

How can I format the exponent? E.g. no leading 0 (2 digits) or always 3 or 4 digits (1 or 2 leading zeroes).

Comment: I'm using Ruby 1.8.6-p111 on Windows. Problem is that 1.8.7 does not include the 0, so my tests fail.

Comment: You are right. It's not Ruby version related, just OS related.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately. Please enter all your comments as answer, so I can accept it. "It's not possible" is a valid answer, although not satisfying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby's [`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001432) is just a wrapper around the native libc [`snprintf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/snprintf.html). From `sprintf.c` (Ruby 1.9.2-p180):

```
/*   
 *  call-seq:
 *     format(format_string [, arguments...] )   -> string
 *     sprintf(format_string [, arguments...] )  -> string 
 * [...]
 */

VALUE
rb_f_sprintf(int argc, const VALUE *argv)
{
    return rb_str_format(argc - 1, argv + 1, GETNTHARG(0));
}
```

And inside `rb_str_format`, we find this:

```
case 'f':
case 'g':
case 'G':
case 'e':
case 'E':
case 'a':
case 'A':
    /* ... */
    snprintf(&buf[blen], need, fbuf, fval);
```

So you should get the same results on a single platform but not necessarily the same results on different platforms (even after taking the usual floating point issues into account). Ruby's `sprintf` doesn't offer any way to control the specific formatting of the exponent so you are at the mercy of the OS's libc (i.e. you of luck, libc has no mercy).

If necessary, you could use `sprintf` and then normalize the format with some greasy regex mangling. Not exactly a pleasant solution but you do what you have to do.